# Newbie: Fusion Table Legend

Tags: html, dictionary, google-fusion-tables, legend

I am Public History major, mapping historical buildings in Annapolis MD. I made a Google Spreadsheet with the 1,415 historic properties and all documentation from fed and state databases. I am not a coder. I want to turn this into a mobile walking tour map where people can choose the type of house from the legend, like all Victorian Homes, or all Colonial Homes, and have them plotted to view and walk to.

My questions are:
1.  Is it possible to choose a text column, like primary style: Victorian, and make it the legend?
2.  Can I add audio files to a fusion table, so I can add stories about the property or the person who build the property, so people can listen to the story?
3.  It there a way to turn this map into an app?

Again, I am not a coder, but I am taking two classes next semester to learn about making apps (HTML5), and I need to know if this is even possible, and if you have any stuff I can read that will help a laymen, I'd appreciate it.

Here is the link to the fusion table: [Historic Annapolis Map](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1RUffU8cRaz6o_1XPlH8XyhGLT6PB04v2ly6OAec) (https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1RUffU8cRaz6o_1XPlH8XyhGLT6PB04v2ly6OAec)

Thanks.
Melanie

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to choose a text column, like primary style: Victorian, and make it the legend?

You could do this with some coding, but the automatic legends only work for marker icons when you use the bucketing approach rather than storing the icon names in a column,

> Can I add audio files to a fusion table, so I can add stories about the property or the person who build the property, so people can listen to the story?

Sure, as long as they are hosted on YouTube or Vimeo.

> It there a way to turn this map into an app?

You can use Tools > Publish to get either an <iframe> that can be embedded in another site, or the HTML and JavaScript to put in your own page. But it there's no automatic way to create a mobile app.